# Custom title on modal button while using a onclick on it

Tags: javascript

I have a modal button that call a ajax function. I pass an "id" as argument of the function.

```
  <div class="modal-footer" >
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cierra</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="myModalId" data-customer-id="myModalId"  onclick="myCall(this)" >Erase</button>
  </div>
```

"myModalId" is the the parameter I have to pass to the  mycall funtion using data-customer-id.

the mycall script is:

```
function myCall(self) {
                    self = $(self);                      
                    var point = $('#myModal #'+self.data("customer-id")).text();
                    //alert(point);     
                        var request = $.ajax({
                                            url: "./php/deleteLocation.php",
                                            type: "GET",            
                                            data: { pointPHP:  point},
                                            success: function(response) {
                                                        location.reload();      
                                            }               
                                            });

                    request.done(function(msg) {
                        $("#mybox").html(msg);
                        $('#myModal').modal('hide');

                    });

                    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                        alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
                        $('#myModal').modal('hide');

                    });
                }
```

I works but the title of the button is the same of the argument (ie 231), while I want a custom title like "Erase".

Where is my foult?

Comment: what is your `myCall()` code?

Comment: I just edit with the call function. Altough the problem is with the modal button title, not with the script

Comment: http://jsbin.com/sonadivoda/edit?html,output Works On My Machine™. Something else is changing the buttons title.

Comment: on your example on My Machine™, no id="" are present, so problem not appears